# Query generated in sequelize is returning values in dbeaver but not working in the program?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have some sequelize code which is generating a query in terminal, which when I run on dbeaver for Postgres is giving me the results i need from the database, but in the program itself it is failing to fetch the results and is returning null. Am putting the code and the query here:

```
let whereClauseArr1 = []; 
let currentDate = moment(dateNow).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
whereClauseArr1.push(db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('date',db.sequelize.col('activity_date')),'=', currentDate)); 
whereClauseArr1.push(db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.col('emp_id'), emp.id)); 
var empData = await db.UserActivity.findAll({ where:whereClauseArr1});
```

The two whereClause conditions are the two limitations that we need for getting data from UserActivity table,the emp_id and activity_date. And the entire codeBlock is placed inside for loop where emp belongs to data array of different employee ids.Now empData should return a value if eg. user_activity has the date: 2022-11-05 00:00:00.000 +0530, and the current date is : 2022-11-05. The program generates the following query in the terminal:

```
select "x", "y", "z" 
from "user_activities" as "UserActivity" 
where ("UserActivity"."deletedAt" is null 
    and (date("activity_date") = '2022-11-05' 
    and "user_id" = '34d1fa38-4e0d-11ed-9641-53842d47c054'));
```

Now when I run this query in dbeaver, I get the proper result if I put the current date in the Postgres database, but for some reason , in the terminal, the output is always coming as null, for empData , even if I put today's date in the database.How can the query generated in the terminal run properly in the database, but fail to work for the program?Could anyone maybe please point out a solution to this situation and why there's a difference in output between dbeaver and the terminal here?

Comment: What is the data type of `activity_date`? If it is `timestamp with time zone`, the session time zone will make a difference. But perhaps it is something trivial, like you are connection to two different databases.

Comment: Yes, it is timestamp with a timezone and Yes! Turn out it was a time difference issue in the end , which I might not have properly taken into account for different records. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Great. If you write the query like `activity_date >= CAST('2022-11-05' AS timestamp with time zone) AND activity_date < CAST('2022-11-06' AS timestamp with time zone)`, it could use an index.